# Interpretation of the dual of the minimum spanning tree

Tags: duality-theorems

I am looking at the dual solution obtained for the minimum spanning tree problem. How can I extract the information on which edges are included in the optimal solution?

The dual formulation that I am using is;

$
\begin{align}
~\max &~ z (|V|-1) + \sum_{S  \subseteq V : |S| \neq \emptyset} (|S|-1) y_{s} \\
\label{DMST2}
s.t. &~ z + \sum_{S: (i,j) \in E(S)}^{} y_{s} \leq w_{ij} &  \forall (i,j) \in E \\
\label{DMST3}
&~y_{s} \leq 0 & \forall S  \subseteq V : |S| \neq \emptyset 
\end{align}
$

Suppose I have the following toy graph with the adjacency matrix below.

$ \begin{bmatrix}
{0, 20, 5, 5, 15} \\
{20, 0, 9, 8, 23} \\
{5, 9, 0, 8, 7} \\
{5, 8, 8, 0, 14} \\
{15, 23, 7, 14, 0} 
\end{bmatrix}  $

Now, I look at the dual solution obtained after solving the model. First, let's see the subsets used to generate the dual constraints.

[{1} {2} {1 2} {3} {1 3} {2 3} {1 2 3} {4} {1 4} {2 4} {1 2 4} {3 4} {1 3 4}
{2 3 4} {1 2 3 4} {5} {1 5} {2 5} {1 2 5} {3 5} {1 3 5} {2 3 5} {1
2 3 5} {4 5} {1 4 5} {2 4 5} {1 2 4 5} {3 4 5} {1 3 4 5} {2 3 4 5}]

The following solution is obtained from the dual.

{1 3}  : $y_5 =-2$

{1 4}   : $y_9 =-3$

{1 3 5} : $y_{21} =-1$

z = 8

For instance, how can I conclude that the edge {2-4} is in the optimal solution?

Comment: May I ask how you obtained the solution from the dual?

Comment: It's been more than two years since I asked the question, but I guess I solved the dual using Cplex in Java API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply complementary slackness in both directions: $$y_S < 0 \implies \sum_{(i,j) \in E(S)} x_{i,j} = |S| - 1 \tag1$$
and
$$x_{i,j} > 0 \implies z + \sum_{S: (i,j) \in E(S)} y_S = w_{i,j}. \tag2$$

For example, $(1)$ and $y_5=-2<0$ imply that $x_{1,3}=1$.
Similarly, $(1)$ and $y_9<0$ imply that $x_{1,4}=1$, which in turn implies $x_{3,4}=0$ from the primal constraint for $\{1,3,4\}$.
Also, $(1)$ and $y_{21}<0$ imply that $x_{1,3}+x_{1,5}+x_{3,5}=2$.

You can also use the contrapositive of $(2)$ to deduce $x_{1,2}=x_{1,5}=x_{2,3}=x_{2,5}=x_{4,5}=0$, which implies that $x_{3,5}=1$.

Now the primal cardinality constraint yields $x_{2,4}=1$.